# Throwing an exception to indicate element not found

Tags: java, design-patterns

In below code I'm throwing an exception if an element is not found in a String list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestException {

    private static List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        strList.add("1");
        strList.add("2");
    }
    public static void main(String argsp[]) {

        try {
            String res = new TestException().findId("1");
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            String res = new TestException().findId("11");
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String findId(String id) throws Exception {

        for(String str : strList){
            if(id.equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
                return str;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Exception Thrown - element not found");

    }

}
```

when run output is :

```
1
java.lang.Exception: Exception Thrown - element not found
    at com.fmr.fc.portlet.actionabledashboard.throttling.TestException.findId(TestException.java:40)
    at com.fmr.fc.portlet.actionabledashboard.throttling.TestException.main(TestException.java:24)
```

To keep code volume low in asking question I'm throwing Exception but I will throw a custom exception.
The reason I'm throwing an exception is that the custom exception is caught further up call stack to indicate an error.

But is it bad practice throwing an exception in this way - findId is throwing an exception if an id is not found ?

Comment: Is the item supposed to be in the list (in which case it's an error if it's not) or is it normal for the item to not be in the list?

Comment: @immibis its normal for the item to be in the list

Comment: but is it also normal for the item to not be in the list?

Comment: @immibis no, that is not normal behavior (but it could occur)

Comment: In general, an exception should be thrown when something abnormal has occurred. If there's a method that converts a string to an integer, and the string is not a valid integer, it should throw an exception. If there's a method that tells you whether a string is a valid integer, it shouldn't throw an exception (it should just return false).

Comment: I think it could be judged as correct or wrong based on the scenario. For example - If I was writing code for a School management system,  if I am looking for results of 3rd test of a student in a DB and the value is not there in the returned list of tests, I would rather throw an exception like `ElementNotFound` and let the caller / parent class handle it. Why do I have to introduce additional logic to check for such cases?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is bad practice. You should write a function that passes a boolean and allow the program to use this to determine what to do.

Exceptions should only be use to handle very rare, completely unavoidable events. They shouldn't be part of the standard logic of your code, they are (surprise!) the exception to the rule. Things that might (possibly) happen, but are very unlikely and you really, really couldn't find a way to stop them.

Comment: "Exceptions should only be use to handle very rare, completely unavoidable events." I disagree, exceptions must be done every time you don't know how to correct a failure.

Comment: I'd agree that failures are a subset of the use cases for exceptions, but are not the only subset. An alternative use might be something like an InterruptedException, where technically nothing has failed but a sudden change in program flow needs to be sent back up the stack. 

I do think in the context of the question the definition is helpful, but you are right that its too vague in a larger sense...

Answer (score 0):

In general it is bad practice to throw an exception in this type of situation. Try modifying your function to return an Optional as used in the guava pattern. Some details [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained):